# Query to get the current values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following tables

```
menu_supp
menu_id    supp_id    supp_weight    supp_load_follow
1          29         10.00          1
1          31         20.00          2

supps
supp_id    user_id    supp_name
29         1          Test supp 1
31         1          Test supp 2

supps_prop
supp_id    supp_dry_w    supp_price    supp_date
29         95.00         125.00        2015-10-25
29         94.00         124.00        2015-11-06
29         94.00         128.00        2015-11-12
31         25.00         200.00        2015-06-25
```

Now I've got this query:

```
SELECT s.supp_id, s.supp_name, ms.supp_weight, sp.supp_price, sp.supp_dry_weight
FROM menu_supp ms
LEFT JOIN supps s ON ms.supp_id = s.supp_id
LEFT JOIN supps_prop sp ON ms.supp_id = sp.supp_id
WHERE menu_id = 1
GROUP BY s.supp_id
ORDER BY ms.supp_load_follow ASC
```

Which gives me this result:

```
supp_id     supp_name   supp_weight     supp_price  supp_dry_weight
29          Test supp 1 10.00           125.00      95.00
31          Test supp 2 20.00           200.00      25.00
```

From supp 29 it gets the oldest value. Where it should take the value based on the current date. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You are using a MySQL (mis)feature that allows columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  Fix your query to use a `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` to get the most recent date.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff says, you are mis using a feature. While you say you get the oldest value, the value you get is from an undefined row. May be the oldest, may be the newest, and it may change in future.

Comment: Thank your @GordonLinoff for you answer. As it may seem logical for you, it doesn't for me. I'm no sql expert. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I will try to explain below.

Comment: Indeed, 'feature' is debatable term in this instance.

Comment: @LinkinTED . . . It makes no sense to group by a column such as `ms.supp_load_follow` and then include columns such as `s.supp_id` in the `select`.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so the values of these extra columns come from indeterminate rows.  (This is permitted by the ANSI standard when the `group by` columns are a unique key, but that is not the case here.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thank you for your explanation. It makes sense to me now. I didn't know I was abusing `group by`, and since it almost gave me the  desired result, I thought I was on the right way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query without the `group by` and using inner joins. It appears to me that no *supp_id* would be inserted into *menu_supp* that is not already defined in *supps*. I suppose it would be possible to have no entry in *supps_prop* but that looks doubtful also. If I am wrong, simply change it back.

```
SELECT  s.supp_id, s.supp_name, ms.supp_weight, sp.supp_price,
        sp.supp_dry_w, sp.supp_date
FROM    menu_supp ms
JOIN    supps s
    ON  s.supp_id = ms.supp_id
JOIN    supps_prop sp
    ON  sp.supp_id = ms.supp_id
WHERE menu_id = 1
ORDER BY ms.supp_load_follow;
```

I've also added the date to make it easier to follow. The results are all four possible rows:

```
supp_id supp_name   supp_weight supp_price supp_dry_w supp_date
------- ---------   ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------
29      Test supp 1 10.00       125.00     95.00      2015-10-25
29      Test supp 1 10.00       124.00     94.00      2015-11-06
29      Test supp 1 10.00       128.00     94.00      2015-11-12
31      Test supp 2 20.00       200.00     25.00      2015-06-25
```

Obviously, you only want to join with the *prop* information contained in the row with the current or most recent date. That date is the largest value still in the past. Which can be found like this:

```
SELECT  s.supp_id, s.supp_name, ms.supp_weight, sp.supp_price,
        sp.supp_dry_w, sp.supp_date
FROM    menu_supp ms
JOIN    supps s
    ON  s.supp_id = ms.supp_id
JOIN    supps_prop sp
    ON  sp.supp_id = ms.supp_id
    and sp.supp_date =(
        select  Max( supp_date )
        from    supps_prop
        where   supp_id = ms.supp_id
            and supp_date <= NOW() )
WHERE menu_id = 1
ORDER BY ms.supp_load_follow;
```

Don't let the subquery concern you. Since the combination of *supp_id* and *supp_date* are the most obvious PK for the *prop* table, those fields should already be indexed, making this an impressively fast query.

See it in action at [sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52b82/2/0)

Comment: That is a nice query and works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the supp_date is unique for a supp_id then you can use the following to get the value for the latest date:-

```
SELECT s.supp_id, s.supp_name, ms.supp_weight, sp.supp_price, sp.supp_dry_weight
FROM menu_supp ms
LEFT JOIN supps s 
ON ms.supp_id = s.supp_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT supp_id, MAX(supp_date) AS max_supp_date
    FROM supps_prop
    GROUP BY supp_id
) sub0
ON ms.supp_id = sub0.supp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN supps_prop sp 
ON sub0.supp_id = sp.supp_id
AND sub0.max_supp_date = sp.supp_date
WHERE menu_id = 1
ORDER BY ms.supp_load_follow ASC
```

This gets the max supp_date for each supp_id and joins that back to the supps_prop table to get the other fields from it.

EDIT - Coping with either the highest date, or the lowest date after today is a bit more complicated.

I would suggest having 2 sub queries. One to get the highest date for each supp_id and one to get the lowest date on or after today for each supp_id. If the 2nd is found then use that, if not use the first. Not tested but:-

```
SELECT s.supp_id, s.supp_name, ms.supp_weight, COALESCE(sp1.supp_price, sp0.supp_price), COALESCE(sp1.supp_dry_weight, sp0.supp_dry_weight)
FROM menu_supp ms
LEFT JOIN supps s 
ON ms.supp_id = s.supp_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT supp_id, MAX(supp_date) AS max_supp_date
    FROM supps_prop
    GROUP BY supp_id
) sub0
ON ms.supp_id = sub0.supp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN supps_prop sp0 
ON sub0.supp_id = sp0.supp_id
AND sub0.max_supp_date = sp0.supp_date
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT supp_id, MIN(supp_date) AS max_supp_date
    FROM supps_prop
    WHERE supp_date >= CURDATE()
    GROUP BY supp_id
) sub1
ON ms.supp_id = sub1.supp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN supps_prop sp1 
ON sub1.supp_id = sp1.supp_id
AND sub1.max_supp_date = sp1.supp_date
WHERE menu_id = 1
ORDER BY ms.supp_load_follow ASC
```

EDIT - An explanation of GROUP BY, etc:-

GROUP BY is used for aggregate functions; these are functions that give a value over a range of rows which share common field values. For example, SUM would be used to add up the values of the fields over multiple rows often for a shared value (ie, maybe the SUM of order values for a customer id). The shared value field is used given in the GROUP BY field.

In normal standard SQL all the returned non aggregate fields returned by the SELECT statement **must** be mentioned in the GROUP BY statement. This makes logical sense as if they are not mentioned then the values for a group of rows could be different and then there is the problem of which one to choose.

However there are times when this can be a bit too restrictive. For example if you are grouping by a customer id then the customer name is directly related to this customer id. MySQL does allow you to return non aggregate fields in the SELECT statement that are not specified in the GROUP BY clause, but if the values vary over the rows that are grouped together then which value is chosen is not specified; it could be from any of the rows, and indeed there is no reason that it might not change in the future or when using a different storage engine.

Sometimes GROUP BY is abused to return unique rows, in the way that DISTINCT is meant to be used.

In your original query

> SELECT s.supp_id, s.supp_name, ms.supp_weight, sp.supp_price,
>   sp.supp_dry_weight FROM menu_supp ms LEFT JOIN supps s ON ms.supp_id =
>   s.supp_id LEFT JOIN supps_prop sp ON ms.supp_id = sp.supp_id WHERE
>   menu_id = 1 GROUP BY s.supp_id ORDER BY ms.supp_load_follow ASC

you are using GROUP BY s.supp_id. While s.supp_name is dependent on this, ms.supp_weight and sp.supp_price are not. There could be numerous values of each of these for any s.supp_id. MySQL has just used the value from one of the grouped rows for these and doesn't really care which row it chose to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there can be a `supp_date` that lies in the future, but it should take the one not older than the date of today.

Comment: With your example data you have 3 dates for supp_id 29. One is 6th November (today) and the other is the 12th of November. Which of these would you like returned? My query should return the row for the 12th of November. My concern would be if you have multiple rows for a supp_id each with the same date.

Comment: It should return today. And when executing it tomorrow, it should also return the value from the 6th (until the 12th).

Comment: thanks for the expanded explanation on the subject. I know realise what I was doing wrong. Looking at your query... which looks amazing, I'm thinking that I'm better off by filtering it with PHP.